# problem of table edit while using the table button. so i am creating the student registration form using crud operation. encountering problem in edit

Tags: javascript

```
       function editrow(){
                         
var table = document.getElementById('show');

var rowCount = table.rows.length;

var noRowSelected = 1;

for(var i=1; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if(rowCount <= 1) {
               break;
            }
            document.getElementById("fname").value = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("lname").value = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("email").value = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("age").value = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("dob").value = row.cells[4].innerHTML;
            document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value  = row.cells[5].innerHTML;
            document.array.toString().value = row.cells[6].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("myselect").value = row.cells[7].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("myfile").value = row.cells[8].innerHTML;
       }
   }
       }
```

so i am have created the edit button while linking its onclick function to this script. so while changing any given input i am unable to edit any input

and this is html code for the given format.....

```
<html>
    <head>
    
        <title>Table</title>
        
    <body>  
                        <div class="table-responsive">
            
            
            <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 50%;" id="sam">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-xs-6 text-center " >Full Name</th>
                        <td class="col-xs-6"><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>
                
                
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-xs-6 text-center " >Phone no</th>
                        <td class="col-xs-6"><input type="number" name="lname" id="lname" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-xs-6 text-center " >Email</th>
                        <td class="col-xs-6"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-xs-6 text-center " >Age</th>
                        <td class="col-xs-6"><input type="number" name="age" id="age" class="form-control" size="3"></td>
                    </tr>
    
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-xs-6 text-center " >Date Of Birth</th>
                        <td class="col-xs-6"><input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>
    
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-xs-6 text-center " >Gender</th>
                        <td class="form-check text-center " class="col-xs-6"><div id="rates">
                            <input type="radio" id="r1" name="gender" value="Male" class=""> Male
                            <input type="radio" id="r2" name="gender" value="FeMale"class=""> Female
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-xs-6 text-center " >Hobbies</th>
                        <td class="form-check text-center " class="col-xs-6"><div id="rates">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="r1" name="hobbies" value="sports"> sports
                            <input type="checkbox" id="r2" name="hobbies" value="Artcraft"> artcraft
                            <input type="checkbox" id="r2" name="hobbies" value="movies"> movies
                            <input type="checkbox" id="r2" name="hobbies" value="reading"> reading
    
    
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    
    
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-xs-6 text-center "  >Course</th>
                        <td class="text-center col-xs-6"> 
                            <select id= "myselect" class="btn btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" >
                            <option value="MBA" name="course"> MBA</option>
                            <option value="Mtech" name="course"> Mtech</option>
                            <option value="Btech" name="course"> Btech</option>
                            <option value="BBA" name="course"> BBA</option>
                            </select>
    
    
                        </td>
                    
                        
                    </tr>
    
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-xs-6 text-center " > Attach files</th>
                        <td class="col-xs-6 text-center ">
                            <input type="file" name="file" id="myfile">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    
                </div>
    
            </table>
    
                  <!--button for input and output-->
                        <input type="button" name="button" id="btn" value="Add" onclick="AddRow()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="margin: 10px;">
                         
                        <input type="button" name="button" id="edit" value="edit" onclick="editrow()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="margin: 10px;">
    
                
                        <input type="reset" name="button" id="rst" value="clear" onclick="removerow()" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" style="margin: 10px;">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi g rav and welcome to Stack Overflow. Isn't the script looking for checkboxes in the first cell of a row? But that's not the table you've shown in the post. Please click the help button in the first row of this page, take the tour and search the help center for articles about "how to ask a good question", "how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example", and "how do I format my posts". At the moment it's hard to say what be wrong with code we don't know about :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am facing problem while saving the data from modal form to my tbody table. since the coding is too big, it shall be extremely unnecessary to add.